# Fetch all data by user id laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, eloquent, laravel-5

I am new in laravel app development. I have a `userEducation` table. where I store my user's educational background. There can be multiple rows for a single user. Everything is OK. But when I am fetching data from `userEducation` table for a single user, It returns all data. How can I get single user's all data from `userEducation` table.

Below this is my controller class

```
class userController extends Controller{
public function index(){
}

public function show($id){
}

public function edit(){
    $educations=userEducation::all();
    return view('auth.user_edit',['educations'=>$educations]);
}
}
```

Anyone help me plesae :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `hasMany` relationship in your User model and a `belongsTo` relationship in your `userEducation` model.

```
/** User Model*/
public function educations(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\userEducation');
}
```

Then of course the inverse for the Education model

```
/** Education Model */

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then you can do `$educations = Auth::user()->educations` to get the educations that belong to the current user session. If you need it for a specific user, then do  `$educations = User::find($id)->educations;`

Comment: Dear, now showing an error. "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found"

Comment: Add `use Auth;` above your class